# Missing Scrollbars in IE - ASP.NET CSS3

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, scrollbars

When I run below code in IE, it doesn't show any scroll bars. I am developing this using ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2013. I am not able to see under laying text when I reduce the size of IE window.

Please suggest on how to see the scroll-bars. Issue is same with all the browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE 11)

Design.css:

```
html {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI'; overflow: auto;
    background-color: #2a6c9d;
}
body {
    background-color: #3e90bf;
    color: white; overflow: auto;
}
.header-cont {
    width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0px;
}
.header {
    background-color: #bf1e4b; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px; width: 960px; margin: 0px auto; margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.siteLogo {
    float: left; width: 118px; height: 110px; border-radius: 10px; margin-left: 6px;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: 600; position: relative; font-size: 60px; float: right; margin-right: 15px; margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.menuStrip {
    background: #bf1e4b; clear: both; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; 
}
.horCellSpacing {
    border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px 2px; width: 950px;
}
.menuItem {
    font-size: small; text-align: center; min-width: 100px; padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px; background-color: #e56d15; border: 1px solid #e56d15;
}
.menuItem:hover {
    cursor: pointer; background-color: #ffa15b; border: 1px solid white; color: #552604; text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #feeaf5;
}
.content {
    background-color: #00A0B1; width: 960px; margin: 0px auto; 
    padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px;
}
footer {
    text-align: center; position: static; z-index: 10; padding: 5px; display: grid; width: 960px; margin: 0px auto;
    min-height: 20px; margin-top: 8px; bottom: 0px; background-color: gray;
}
```

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/CodeBehind.js"></script>
    <link href="StyleSheets/Design.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Navjyot Foundation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="header-cont">
        <div class="header">
            <img src="Images/LogoDark.png" class="siteLogo"/><h1>NAVJYOT FOUNDATION</h1>
        <div class="menuStrip">
            <table class="horCellSpacing">
                <tr>
                    <td class="menuItem">Home</td><td class="menuItem">About Us</td><td class="menuItem">Members</td>
                    <td class="menuItem">Events</td><td class="menuItem">Photo Gallery</td><td class="menuItem">Video Gallery</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.
            Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.
            Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.
            Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.
            Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.
            Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.
            Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.
            Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.
            Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.
            Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.
            Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.
            Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.
        </div>
    <footer>Copyright © 2014 - 2017 Navjyot Foundation. All Right Reserved.</footer>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found what was the issue.. :-) BTW, I was nesting "content" Div inside the "header" Div, which was made to stick to the top of the page and thus making everything stick to the top of the page.

Comment: However, Now I ran in to another problem. After I move the "content" out of "header" Div. The "content" and "footer" Div is appearing slightly moved towards left and not in align with the header Div. Please HELP :-|